# Javascript getCurrentPosition() function giving me incorrect latitude and longitude values on localhost

Tags: javascript, php

```
Here is my code...

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Geeting User Location</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="getLocation()">Click here to get your address</button><br><br>
        <label>Address: </label>
        <textarea cols="100" rows="5" id="demo"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){showPosition(position)}, null, {
                maximumAge: 75000,
                timeout: 30000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
            });
        }
        else
        {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position)
    {
        var locApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude+"&key=MY_API_KEY_HERE";

        $.ajax({
          url: locApi,
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var address = data.city;
            address += data.region;
            address += data.country;
            $("#demo").append(JSON.stringify(address));
          },
          error: function() {
             $('#demo').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
          },
       });
    }
</script>
```

I want to get the city, region, country name through latitude & longitude values and append it to the textarea when user click on the button. I want to know where I am wrong. Does Geolocation not gives correct latitude & longitude values on localhost.

Comment: you say it's "wrong" ... how far away is it from where it should be?

Comment: It was givinig me 150 to 200km far location

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition and https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-geolocation/

If you are using a device that does not have **high-accuracy GPS**, it is likely basing location of broad assumptions such as your IP address or where your ISP (Internet Service Provider) is located.

You should also get an `Accuracy` measurement with the location so you can have an estimation of how accurate the information you've gotten is.